# My .HTACCESS Issues (Final Ones)

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I explained neatly.

This ***Code 1*** works properly with my INDEX pages (id est `example.com/C` Index of Terms starting with the letter C, instead of opening `example.com/?open=Encyclopedia&letter=C`):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ((LJ).*) /?open=encyclopedia&letter=$2 [NE,L,QSA] # LJ Double-Letter Fix
RewriteRule ((NJ).*) /?open=encyclopedia&letter=$2 [NE,L,QSA] # NJ Double-Letter Fix
RewriteRule ((D\xC5\xBD).*) /?open=encyclopedia&letter=$2 [NE,L,QSA] # DŽ Double-Letter Fix
RewriteRule (([\x00-\xF48FBFBF].|\w).*) /?open=encyclopedia&letter=$2 [NE,L,QSA] # A-O-S Single-Letter Fix; Loads every other single-letter letter
```

It works *finally* fine with all the Index letters (including Š/Đ/Č/Ć/Ž and LJ/NJ/DŽ) and without errors. Now I have this ***Code 2***:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([A-Z](?:[^\x00-\xF48FBFBF]+|[A-Z])?).*$ /?open=encyclopedia&letter=$1&term=$0 [B,NE,L,QSA]
```

Which also works finally fine with all the Terms (id est `example.com/Astronomy`: Term page for explanation for **Astronomy**, instead of opening `example.com/?open=Encyclopedia&letter=A&term=Astronomy`), but it:

**Issue #1**: *won't* open any Term page starting with Š/Đ/Č/Ć/Ž... Example:
• `example.com/Đavo` should redirect to `example.com/?open=Encyclopedia&letter=Đ&term=Đavo`
• `example.com/Škorpija (Astrologija)` should redirect to `example.com/?open=Encyclopedia&letter=Š&term=Škorpija (Astrologija)`
• `example.com/Đžin` should redirect to `example.com/?open=Encyclopedia&letter=DŽ&term=Džin`
I have not tested it with `NJ`/`LJ`/`DŽ` yet.

**Issue #2**:
***Code 1*** and ***Code 2*** should be merged together and working. I tried to do it, but without success.

Comment: unicode ranges won't work there, it's your mistake. If you mean bosnian letters, then this set `[ČĆǄǅĐŠŽǇǈǊǋ]` would be `(\xC4\x8C|\xC4\x86|\xC7\x84|\xC7\x85|\xC4\x90|\xC5\xA0|\xC5\xBD|\xC7\x87|\xC7\x88|\xC7\x8A|\xC7\x8B)` and the rule like this `RewriteRule ^(\xC4\x8C|\xC4\x86|\xC7\x84|\xC7\x85|\xC4\x90|\xC5\xA0|\xC5\xBD|\xC7\x87|\xC7\x88|\xC7\x8A|\xC7\x8B|[A-Z]).*$ /script.php?open=encyclopedia&letter=$1&term=$0 [NE,L,QSA]`

Comment: use `[^/]*` instead of `.*` due to some unicode byte...

Comment: I see you did not read the Question carefully; I meant only **Š**, **Đ**, **Č**, **Ć**, **Ž**, and not the rest. :-) However... ...I edited your Rule with the necessary letters (now is `RewriteRule ^(\xC5\xA0|\xC4\x90|\xC4\x8C|\xC4\x86|\xC5\xBD|[A-Z]).*$ ?open=encyclopedia&letter=$1&term=$0 [NE,L,QSA]`, and I attached it to the **Code 1** above, but it won't work... ...It opens Index page, and not the Term page I try to open with it.

Comment: I meant all bosnian extended unicode latin characters! This rule tested and works good with all those symbols: `RewriteRule "^(\xC4\x8C|\xC4\x86|\xC7\x84|\xC7\x85|\xC4\x90|\xC5\xA0|\xC5\xBD|\xC7\x87|\xC7\x88|\xC7\x8A|\xC7\x8B|[A-Z])[^/]*$" "/script.php?open=encyclopedia&letter=$1&term=$0" [NE,L,QSA]`. It's assumed this rule replaces all/most of your rules.

Comment: note, that copy/pasted text from this site may contain odd `??`

Comment: Well done! I have just tested it — Thank You! Can you post your Answer now as the main one?